# MarginLeft From Button

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I have create a RelativeLayout with buttons inside.
I'm using this xml code for create four buttons side by side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <Button
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="75.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
        <Button
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="165dp"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginRight="119.0dp" />
        <Button
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="75.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />
        <Button
            android:text="Enter"
            android:layout_marginLeft="455dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that my margin is been started from RelativeLayout  and not from my left object which in this case is Button.
So my question is: Will i have any problems if i will run application in different screen sizes??

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? Create an Android Emulator to mimic the screen sizes you want to test for.

Comment: For all screen sizes use linear layout and create nested layout .. so that buttons will be at same place for all screen sizes..

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that my margin is been started from RelativeLayout and
>   not from my left object which in this case is Button.

You could put your button to the right of the other button and the margin will be between them.

Example:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/blue" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button"
            android:background="@color/accent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you bro! That i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Please try that

-With linear layout you can make perfect drawings, I define every button "weight". That do thats They all share the line width evenly. If we say one to two, it will have twice as much space in the same line as the others

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <Button
                android:text="7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button
                android:text="8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button
                android:text="9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button
                android:text="ENTER"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```